# Extracting blank space between buffers regions

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have a set of parallel lines with standard distance of 1.4m and I have created a buffer of 0.70cm for each row of the lines. Now I need to identify the regions where the buffers do not touch, which is where the distance between the lines is greater than 1.4m.
Image for example,  I need to save the blanks between the buffers:

[image]

I created a convex hull of shp and then used the symmetric difference to get the blanks, the problem is that all spaces are united in one feature, I want to separate them.

I do not know if there is another way to do it, any suggestions are welcome! I use QGIS and I'm learning postgis.

[image]